# using between function in oracle last data is not printed in selecting name while in salary last value is included

Tags: oracle

```
SELECT name from emp 
WHERE salary BETWEEN 'A%' AND 'K%'
```

not printing the name with K but when we using

```
SELECT salary from emp 
WHERE salary BETWEEN 5000 AND 10000
```

In this 10000 is included, why?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that while comparing salary, you are using EXACT values. But for names, you are using wildcards.

So if you want all records between A and K, then use below query to get exact result

```
      select *  from emp
      where substr(ename,1,1) between 'A' and 'K'
```

Let me explain what I assume but please correct me if I am wrong. ORACLE sorts strings based on ASCII values. If 2 varchar has same first ASCII values, then it uses second ASCII value and so on. So as per Oracle 'K' < 'K1' or 'KA'. Hence you don't get employees starting with K in your output.

Now the like clause is bit confusing. For varchar when you include wild card, they behave bit differently for upper and lower limit. So > 'A%' will not include A, but < 'K%' will include K. So between 'A%' and 'K%' will behave differently from between 'A' and 'K'.

See this example

```
      with emp (ename) as
      (select 'A' from dual union
      select 'A1' from dual union
      select 'KK' from dual union
      select 'K' from dual union
      select 'ZZ' from dual)
      select * from emp
     order by ename
```

Output

```
  ENAME
      A
      A1
      K
      KK
      ZZ
```

Now if you run between query then you would only get A1 and K in your output

```
      with emp (ename) as
      (select 'A' from dual union
      select 'A1' from dual union
      select 'KK' from dual union
      select 'K' from dual union
      select 'ZZ' from dual)
      select * from emp
     where ename > 'A%' and ename <'K%'
```

Output

```
  ENAME
      A1
      K
```